# MYSQL Query to ignore every duplicate

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table which has duplicate rows. I want to do a select which will remove ALL duplicate rows.

I know i can do a GROUP BY but that will still show a single row for the duplicate. What i want is that all the duplicates should be ignored.

E.g

I have a table named "users" which has a column named "username" which have the following values:

1. John
2. Sam
3. Reyaan
4. Reyaan
5. Sam.

So when the select query finishes, it should only show the row with "John" and ignore everything else because Sam and Reyaan were duplicated.

Thanks.

Comment: Have your researched for somthing like `MySQL distinct`?

Comment: @chade_ I think `having` clause would meet the requirement, which need to `filter` the username that only occurs once

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the HAVING clause to make sure there is only one row returned for each of the groups. That way, you'll make sure only names that have specifically 1 instance (not zero, not more than 1) will be returned.

Example:

```
SELECT 
    name
FROM
    people
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(name) = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you exactly what i needed.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `count`  and check the result of count in `having` clause

```
select username
from users
group by username
having count(*) = 1
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/007179/1)

Comment: Thank you exactly what i needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use NOT IN function

```
SELECT username FROM users WHERE username not in (select username from users group by username having count(username)>1)
```

Comment: There is no need for all those inperformant SUB SELECT + GROUP BY + IN clause

Comment: At least you have not posted a duplicate answer

Answer (score -1):

you can use this query to fetch record

```
SELECT name FROM people GROUP BY name HAVING COUNT(name) = 1;
```